# Node get image regardless of environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to make a node module to draw a PDF file that needs to run both server side on Google Cloud Functions and client side in React (create-react-app). Part of the PDF is a logo png. The problem comes from drawing the logo.

On the server side, I can do this:

```
const getLogo = async (): Promise<Buffer> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "../assets/logo.png"),
      (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
          return resolve(data);
        }

        return reject(err);
      }
    );
  });
};

// later on:
const logo = await pdfDoc.embedPng(await getLogo());
```

But I get an error with `fs.readFile` is not a function if running on the client side.

On the client side, its as simple as importing the image:

```
import LOGO_PNG from '../assets/logo.png';

// and then:
const logo = await pdfDoc.embedPng(LOGO_PNG);
```

But neither method works on both server and client side. Is there a way to do this that works regardless of environment?

Comment: `if (environment == CLIENT) return pdfDoc.embedPng(await import('…')) else return fs.promises.readFile(…)`?

Comment: @Bergi good suggestion but that doesn't get past the typescript compiler. It complains about the import format of `import LOGO_PNG from '../assets/logo.png';`.

I get `Cannot find module`. I'm guessing this is due to the project setup for the library

Comment: Yes, it will depend on the project setup. A true isomorphic library is quite hard. You might want to use a build system to produce two distinct libraries, or you only supply the core library that requires an adapter for file loading.

Comment: :'( yea I'm hoping it doesn't get to that point though. Hoping to reduce complexity as much as possible here. I'm already using two different libraries for server vs browser barcode generation here